# How to select all the mesh faces inside surrounding sharp edge faces?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, selection-tools

How to select all the faces inside surrounding sharp edge faces?

Below is simplified example:
I am trying to get all the faces of the pane inside the sharp edged window frame of the car.

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (all options inside the menu) don't work.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Quan .. we can't see the simplified example . You can edit your question to include an image, using the editing toolbar.

Comment: Oh sorry! I will do that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be said, the topology of your reference model *will* give you a hard time. There's no getting around it. Selection will be difficult, shading might be affected; the interpolation of normals across surfaces won't be very predictable. Re-shaping parts will be nearly impossible.

In a more conventional topology, like this:

[image]

..the flow of edge-loops / quad face loops follow the 3D form, and will help you all the way. Selection tools are built for it.

In the mean time, you could try [Select Linked : Flat Faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/linked.html#linked-flat-faces), adjusting the angle to catch the boundary:

[image]

Comment: Wow, Seems great!, Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Hover over faces to select and press <kbd>L</kbd> then select *Sharp* in the popup that appears in the lower left corner.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply! I need to mark the seam first in this method. Is there any way it can auto detect sharp edges in just one selection?

Comment: Sorry for seems lazy question, I just need to do a lot of this kind of work now, so I need to ask.

Comment: what do u mean by sharp edges? sorry i thought u meant the blue lines by sharp edges. and i just saw ur picture now